# How to optimize this select query

Tags: oracle, performance

Hi I'm using the below select query which fetches all the rows from the table based on a single condition. It is like an export that we are geenrating. Here is the query.

```
Select emp_name, phone_number, emp_id from Employees where 
emp_dept = 100;
```

Suppose if i have millions of records here and i'm not allowed to create any temporary table and index, what is the best way to optimize this query. Please note i need all the records of the table so the filters are actually less.

In the process of learning Oracle. So please let me know in case any mistakes are there.

Thanks.

Comment: indexes.indexes.indexes

Comment: Should i put index on emp_dept?

Comment: @MitchWheat, really, really, really? What if the number of rows that match the `emp_dept = 100` predicate is e.g. 5 millions? ;-) Then good luck to OP with his DBAs beating him with a baseball bat for doing so many LIOs. ;-)

Comment: There should be a lot of DBAs in the department with 5 millions employees...

Comment: @Multisync :-D True, but he's in the process of learning Oracle and I believe that `employees` is merely an example. See the "*Suppose if i have millions of records here*" note. What I'm trying to say is that you can't tune a query without knowing all its whereabouts.

Comment: @chikkada, query tuning is very specific to the actual query, data volumes and data patterns. Start with the actual query that will really be executed, including bind variables (not literal values) if they're used (hint: they should be). The next step would be to examine the execution plan to see if Oracle is already finding an optimal plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

> i'm not allowed to create any temporary table and index

then your **only** option seems to be to run this in parallel:

```
select --+ parallel(E,16)
    emp_name, phone_number, emp_id
from employees E
where emp_dept = 100;
```

And your **useful** options are, depending on many factors ...

- to ask your local DBA to add an index for you
- to ask your local DBA to reorganize the table for you (partitioning, clusters)
- to ask your local DBA to create a on-commit fast-refreshable query-rewritable mview for you
- to ask your company to buy Exadata machine for you
- etc.